# How to keep text input area at the bottom of my webview

Tags: html, css, xcode, webview, chat

I'm using a webview inside xcode to render a hosted chat interface.
When I'm using the chat interface from Safari the text input area stays at the bottom at all times.
However when I'm using inside the webview the text area scrolls together with the text after the scroll area is getting higher, and after a while disappears above the fold.
If I close the keyboard (with the "done" button) and reopen it it's back on the bottom.

What CSS configuration do I need to use to keep it at the bottom although the area above it scrolls?

Currently my footer code looks like this:

```
<div class="footer">

                <div class="form-wrapper">
                <form lpformnum="1" _lpchecked="1">

                    <div class="input-group">

                        <input type="text" id="userInput" name="userInput" class="form-control" placeholder="I would like to..." style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAASCAYAAABSO15qAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAPhJREFUOBHlU70KgzAQPlMhEvoQTg6OPoOjT+JWOnRqkUKHgqWP4OQbOPokTk6OTkVULNSLVc62oJmbIdzd95NcuGjX2/3YVI/Ts+t0WLE2ut5xsQ0O+90F6UxFjAI8qNcEGONia08e6MNONYwCS7EQAizLmtGUDEzTBNd1fxsYhjEBnHPQNG3KKTYV34F8ec/zwHEciOMYyrIE3/ehKAqIoggo9inGXKmFXwbyBkmSQJqmUNe15IRhCG3byphitm1/eUzDM4qR0TTNjEixGdAnSi3keS5vSk2UDKqqgizLqB4YzvassiKhGtZ/jDMtLOnHz7TE+yf8BaDZXA509yeBAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: scroll; background-size: 16px 18px; background-position: 98% 50%; cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">

                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" id="SendMessage" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                        </span>

                    </div>

                </form>
                </div>

        </div>
```

and the footer div css:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    height: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* margin-right: auto; */
    /* margin-left: auto; */
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: buttom;
}
```

Before scrolling begins:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: do you know about auto layout ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use position fix and set position to bottom like this:

```
.footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1030;
height: 50px;
max-width: 100%;
background-color: #ffffff;
transition: buttom; /* I use same css which you used and I wonder how this will work*/
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. When using a browser it's ok (even with the "absolute" key) but inside the webview the result is as attached.